# Why Isn't an AutoSuggestBox text "optimized"?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I've been trying to educate myself on performance optimization of UWP since my application is pathetically sloooow.   One really interesting mechanism is setting the IsTextPerformanceVisualizationEnabled flag.  I noticed that 95% of my app's text strings were shown in the bright green color that denotes "optimized", but I have some simple AutoSuggestBoxes that are shown in black.

In fact I wrote a tiny test:

```
       <TextBlock Text="good text block"></TextBlock>  <= shows as optimized
       <TextBlock >bad text block</TextBlock>          <= shows not optimized
       <AutoSuggestBox Text="asb"></AutoSuggestBox>    <= shows not optimized
```

I understand the textblocks.  Can someone explain what is wrong with the AutoSuggestBox?  Or do they just not participate in the "text" testing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starting it's not a `TextBlock`, but a `TextBox` because the user can type into it.
You can see it by outlining it from the Document Outline window and selecting with right mouse button > Edit Template... > Edit a Copy to see it's made with a TextBox and and List Item.

A TextBox text cannot be optimized, because it changes on the user input.